# How to access local host docker registry from within a docker-in-docker (dind) container

Tags: docker, networking, registry, docker-in-docker

I'm running containers in "docker-in-docker" (dind) on a host and would like to pass through a local docker registry (`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2.8`) to be accessible in my "docker-in-docker" dind container.

I realize I can pass through the host network stack with `docker run --network:host dind ...`, however my application requires its own local network stack so in this case I would like to just be able to push/pull images to the host registry (from within the dind container). Is there a good way to achieve this?